# the code does not give the results what I want using equal sign in python

Tags: python, equals, numeric

I do have a code like this.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.zeros(shape = (4,4))
a+= 2
b = np.zeros(shape = (4,4))
b+=2
t = 0
while t<2:
    for i in range(1,3):
        for j in range(1,3):
            if a[i,j] == a[i-1,j]:
                b[i,j] = a[i,j]+1
    print(a,t)
    print(b,t)
    a = b
    t+= 1
```

I am hoping that at t = 2
a = [2 2 2 2, 2 3 3 2, 2 3 3 2, 2 2 2 2] and b = [2 2 2 2, 2 3 3 2, 2 4 4 2, 2 2 2 2]
but in fact at the end of the run the a = [2 2 2 2, 2 3 3 2, 2 4 4 2, 2 2 2 2]

anyone know why? is it because i am declaring a = b? if it is yes, is there any way to do it?
thanks..

Comment: Even if you did not use `a=b` but copied all elements of b to a, there is no reason to assume that the result for a and b will be different at the end of the run as it ends with making them equal. You might want to _begin_ with making them equal, so `a` is always one step behind `b` at the end of the run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `a=b` (which makes `a` and `b` the *same* array) with `a[:,:]=b` (which copies the elements of `b` into `a`).